# Monetary system(or the abscense of it) in an economy where AI and robots have eliminated most jobs

Tags: internal-consistency, economy, artificial-intelligence, robots, money

Where the mejority economic socaity robot have the cloused and personal car 30 ton e.g. tracking [image]

Comment: What is your worldbuilding problem? It seems that you keep stating your opinions to start a debate. We prefer answering proper worldbuilding questions.

Comment: There's no interrogative form either in the title or the body, which is a problem for a question ^^'. If you're willing to discuss economics in the near or far future, but don't have a precise question to be solved, it's alas not the site for the job. This apart, don't confuse work inexistence and resources availability. The latter is I believe  more important in making markets, and therefore trading systems.

Comment: To prevent closure, removed the "opinion" sentence about Star trek replicators, and added a question consistent with the title.. @SabrineCrystal if you don't agree with my edit, please undo it.

Comment: In most high-capitalist countries (America) wealth is no longer created by making and selling things, it is made from having money. The financialization of the economy. American companies are increasing their profit by decreasing their production - some companies make huge profits by making nothing at all (banks, insurance companies, patent farms, money lenders, financial advisors, investment management firms, sports franchises, entertainment complexes for instance). Even if all goods were free, there would be a huge Ponzi scheme investing economy based on the growth and sales of  investments.

Comment: capitalism will never disappear, unless humans disappear.

Answer (score 2):

**Money is not only wages**

I think abolishing money in a world with zero human labour will probably never happen. Money is not only a reward for labour. Your economy needs capital and resources to run properly and to be able to produce and transport free goods for everyone. The value of machines, resources, infrastructure and energy will still be measured in terms of money.

Bread may be free, even grain seeds or cows may be free, but farm land will be sold for money.

Money also provides a balance. Infinite freedom of consumption for every human is not possible. There won't  be a private helicopter for all of us. Money allows us to exchange goods in such a way, that both parties are satisfied. Many goods may become free for the end-consumer, but their producers will require payment (=money).

This is why many rich countries experiment with "base income", that is a certain amount of money every citizen is allowed, as minimal means to stay alive. In your mechanized world this allowance could be more than that, but I bet some animals will be more equal than others.

Comment: The idea of "basic income" is in its name: it will give you enough to eat, keep a roof over your head and other necessities, but unless you carefully manage and save it, you're not going to be using it to buy a brand new car. It's similar to the way universal health care works in Canada: you don't have to worry about the costs of, say, surgery, and a stay in hospital, but if that surgery is for a cosmetic reasons, and you want your own private room, that's on you.

Comment: In wealthy countries, you'll have the option to arrange a basic income - and health care - for everyone. It is a way to prevent poverty. But it requires a good economy, in fact: a wealthy country. And the above question holds even more than that: science and technology allow citizens to be free of any work. In that case, do we still need money ? I think the answer is yes. And we still need (some) work as well..

Comment: A key idea in this discussion is *scarcity*. If there is more demand for something than there is supply, you need a way to portion it out to people. Even if you manage to relieve scarcity of many goods and services (say, bread, or dentistry) that doesn't mean you've relieved scarcity of all goods and services (say, land, or concert tickets, or dentists).